# Does installing a different desktop environment (other than the default) affect "what softwares I can install in my distro"?

Tags: fedora, gnome3, desktop-environment, lxqt

- I use my laptop for work, mainly;
- It has Fedora 32;
- I am affraid to install LXQt and be unable to use softwares I once could have in GNOME.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Installing a new package won't stop you from running GNOME software.  Are you actually experiencing a problem?

Comment: I am considering installing Fedora LXQt spin. I'm just not sure if it affects if I can install any software I could have with GNOME.